# Why this game is a draw?

Tags: draw

[image]

Chess.com gives a draw result. I can't understand why.

Comment: This is unfortunate.  You had many winning moves: https://syzygy-tables.info/?fen=6k1/5p2/3B1Q2/2P2B2/8/4K3/8/8_w_-_-_0_1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Black has no legal move, which is an automated draw by design.
Every move at Black's hand would result in its king in check.

Comment: If black cant move anymore, why isnt white win?

Comment: You might want to study the rules of chess a bit.

Comment: It's called *stalemate*. If a player has no legal move, and is not in check, then it's a draw. You could play a game with different rules if you like (but it wouldn't be standard chess). If you want to know historically why or how that became the rule, you could google "history of stalemate" or start from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stalemate#History_of_the_stalemate_rule

Comment: @OtesUrop For a history of stalemate as a win, loss, or a draw, see https://www.chess.com/article/view/stalemate2

Comment: But hey, Black had one legal move right? f4 is legal right? Why must it be a draw in that position?